# How to change a controller instance variable live from a view in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In our application we have a gem that supplies common code for five web sites running Rails applications. In the gem in the file `lib/theme/controller_module.rb` is the following code:

```
def application_javascripts(*items)
  @application_javascripts ||= []
  @application_javascripts += items
end
```

In the gem in the file `helpers/theme_helper.rb` is the following code:

```
def application_js_include_tag
  if @application_javascripts
    javascript_include_tag( *@application_javascripts)
  end
end
```

The theme gem is in each application's `Gemfile`. In controller code and in helpers the `application_javascripts` executes to track which page-specific JavaScript is used on the page and the `application_js_include_tag` is placed at the bottom of the view to make only those few files available.

Unfortunately, it appears that `@application_javascripts` value is not updated in the view once the view has started to render. Additions to `@application_javascripts` that occur in a helper are not available to the view when `application_js_include_tag` is executed at the bottom of the page. Do I need a separate helper like `application_javascripts` with a variable defined there, and use both in `application_js_include_tag`? Or some other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From its behavior, it appears that a snapshot of `@application_javascripts` is taken at the time rendering starts. Execution of `controller.application_javascripts` during the rendering does not change the value of `@application_javascripts` available in the view. Defining in `helpers/theme_helper.rb`:

```
def application_javascripts(*items)
  controller.application_javascripts(*items)
end
```

also does not change the value. What does work, is to reproduce the code so that `@application_javascripts` is changed by the code resident in the helper file. Defining in `helpers/theme_helper.rb` a duplicate of the controller code:

```
def application_javascripts(*items)
  @application_javascripts ||= []
  @application_javascripts += items
end
```

works fine.